# Despite giving "not null " condition for a given column, i can seem to enter empty values into the table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-insert, create-table

I am facing an error with my mysql table, I have given the default "not null" condition, but despite the same, empty values are being stored in the table

**The code:**

**#CREATING TABLE**

```
my_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test (name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255), DT DATE , email VARCHAR(255), age INTEGER(10), user_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT Primary key)")    
for table in my_cursor:       
  print(table[0])
```

**#inserting record**

```
Record = "INSERT INTO test (name, password, address, DT, email, age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"     
RECORD=[input("ENTER YOUR NAME "),input("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD "),input("ENTER YOUR ADDRESS "),input("ENTER YOUR DOB "),input("ENTER YOUR EMAIL "),input("ENTER YOUR AGE ")]   
my_cursor.execute(Record,RECORD)
mydr.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you are inserting is an empty string (`''`), not a `null` value; those are two different things.

The `not null` constraint prevents the latter, not the former. If you want to prevent the empty string, you can use a check constraint:

```
create table test (
    name varchar(255) not null check(name <> ''), 
    password varchar(255), 
    address varchar(255), 
    dt date, 
    email varchar(255), 
    age integer(10), 
    user_id integer auto_increment primary key
)
```